# R Shiny app -"Disconnected from the server. Reload

Tags: r

I ran my application on rstudio and found nothing wrong with it. All modules worked fine, but when I deployed it to the server, "Disconnected from the server.
Below is my server and ui code

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(navbarPage(
  title="Riboshiny.test",
  tabPanel("Load Data",value = 1,
           sidebarLayout(
             sidebarPanel(fileInput("geneExpressDataFile", "1.Upload gene expression data file",
                                    multiple = FALSE,
                                    accept = c("text/csv",
                                               "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                                               ".csv")),
                          tags$head(tags$style("
          body {
            padding: 0 !important;
          }"))),
             mainPanel(
               h5("Upload your file and the results will be displayed below."),
               tableOutput("geneExpressDataTable")
             )
           )
  ),
  tabPanel("TE Value",value = 2,
           sidebarLayout(
             sidebarPanel(
               strong("The translation efficiency of the gene expression matrix is calculated"),
               br(),
               br(),
               actionButton("starTEvalueCalc","starCalcTE"),
               br(),
               br(),
               downloadButton("downTEvalueresult", "Download Result")
             ),
             mainPanel(
               h5("Click the 'starCalcTE' button in the left column to start calculating your translation efficiency, the results will be displayed below"),
               tableOutput("TEvalueResultTable")

             )
           )),
  tabPanel("RPKM",value = 3,
           sidebarLayout(
             sidebarPanel(
               strong("The translation efficiency of the gene expression matrix is calculated"),
               br(),
               br(),
               downloadButton("downRPKMsult", "Download Result")
             ),
             mainPanel(
               h5("The calculation result of RPKM will be shown below after calculation"),
               tableOutput("RPKMtable")
             )
           )
           ),
  tabPanel("Difference analysis",value = 4,
           sidebarLayout(
             sidebarPanel(
               # helpText("The engine of difference analysis is Riborex"),
               # fileInput("file3", "Upload RNACntTable",
               #           multiple = FALSE,
               #           accept = c("text/csv",
               #                      "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
               #                      ".csv")),
               # fileInput("file4", "Upload RiboCntTable",
               #           multiple = FALSE,
               #           accept = c("text/csv",
               #                      "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
               #                      ".csv")),
               # fileInput("file5", "Upload rnaCond",
               #           multiple = FALSE,
               #           accept = c("text/csv",
               #                      "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
               #                      ".csv")),
               # fileInput("file6", "Upload riboCond",
               #           multiple = FALSE,
               #           accept = c("text/csv",
               #                      "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
               #                      ".csv"))
               
             ),
             mainPanel(
               tableOutput("diffTable")
             )
           )),
  tabPanel("PCA",value = 5,
           sidebarLayout(
             sidebarPanel(
               h5("Download your PCA data results image"),
               br(),
               br(),
               downloadButton("downPCAplot", "Download PCAplot")
             ),
             mainPanel(
               plotOutput("PCAplot",width = 700,height = 560)
             )
           )),
  
))
```

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(DESeq2)
library(edgeR)
library(data.table)
library(riborex)
# library(factoextra)
####公共变量及参数----
PCAcolorBank <- c("#1B00DB","#AA00DB","#DB0051","#00DB22","#E1A00B","#00C5E0")
####自定义函数----
#数据简单处理 id、表达量筛选
dataPreprocessing <- function(x,minCount=1){
  x <- as.data.frame(x)
  xid <- rownames(x)
  xid <- gsub("\\.\\d+$","",xid)
  xid <- gsub(" ","",xid)
  rownames(x) <- xid
  x <- x[apply(x,1,mean) >= minCount,]
  return(x)
}
####提取基因矩阵的样本名
setUpGroup <- function(x){
  tempgroups <- colnames(x)
  tempgroups <-gsub("[0-9]*$","",tempgroups)
  tempgroups <-gsub(" ","",tempgroups)
  tempgroups <-gsub("\\_","",tempgroups)
  tempgroups <-gsub("\\.","",tempgroups)
  tempgroups <- as.data.frame(tempgroups)
  return(tempgroups[,1])
}
####服务器函数----
shinyServer(function(input, output){
####展示用户上传的表达矩阵----
  output$geneExpressDataTable <- renderTable({
    req(input$geneExpressDataFile)
    withProgress(message = "Processing the file you uploaded",{
      incProgress(1/3, "Reading a file.")
      geneExpressDataFile <- read.csv(input$geneExpressDataFile$datapath,header = T)
      incProgress(2/3, "Converting files.")
      geneExpressMatrix <- as.data.frame(geneExpressDataFile)
      incProgress(1, "Read complete.")
      return(head(geneExpressMatrix,n=20))
    })
  },striped=TRUE,bordered = TRUE,width = "auto")
####TEvalue结果计算----
  TEvalueResultTable <- reactive({
    if(input$starTEvalueCalc == 0)
      return(NULL)
    if(input$starTEvalueCalc > 0 & !is.null(input$geneExpressDataFile))
      minCount=1
    geneMatrix <- read.csv(input$geneExpressDataFile$datapath,header = T,row.names = 1)
    geneMatrix <- dataPreprocessing(geneMatrix,minCount)
    tempNumber <- (dim(geneMatrix)[2])/2
    geneMatrix <- geneMatrix%>%
      filter(rowSums(select(., 1:tempNumber)) > 0)
    tempDataFrame1 <- as.data.frame(apply(geneMatrix[,1:tempNumber],1,sum))
    colnames(tempDataFrame1)[1] <- "colname1"
    tempDataFrame2 <- as.data.frame(apply(geneMatrix[,(tempNumber+1):(tempNumber*2)],1,sum))
    colnames(tempDataFrame2)[1] <- "colname2"
    calcDataFrame <- cbind(tempDataFrame1,tempDataFrame2)
    TEcalcDataFrame <- mutate(calcDataFrame,TEvalue=calcDataFrame[2]/calcDataFrame[1])
    TEtable <- cbind(as.data.frame(rownames(geneMatrix)),TEcalcDataFrame$TEvalue)
    colnames(TEtable) <- c("geneID","TEvalue")
    return(TEtable)
  })
####TEvalue的计算结果展示----
  output$TEvalueResultTable <- renderTable({
    return(head(TEvalueResultTable(),n=30))
  },striped=TRUE,bordered = TRUE,width = "auto")
####TE值结果文件的下载----
  output$downTEvalueresult <- downloadHandler(
    filename = "TEvalue.csv",
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(TEvalueResultTable(), file, row.names = FALSE)
    }
  )
####RPKM结果计算----
  RPKMResultTable <- function(x){
    req(input$geneExpressDataFile)
    geneMatrix_2 <- read.csv(input$geneExpressDataFile$datapath,header = T,row.names = 1)
    minCount <- 1
    geneMatrix <- dataPreprocessing(geneMatrix_2,minCount)
    texlens_1 <- read.csv("data/txlensFile/hg38_telen.csv")
    setnames(texlens_1, c('gene', 'length'))
    txlens_1 <-texlens_1[match(rownames(geneMatrix_2), texlens_1$gene), ]
    y <-DGEList(counts = geneMatrix_2, genes = data.frame(Length = txlens_1[, 2]))
    y <- calcNormFactors(y)
    RPKM <- rpkm(y)
    RPKM = RPKM[rowMeans(RPKM) > 1, ]
    normalcount = as.data.frame(RPKM, keep.rownames = T)
    normalcount <- cbind(rownames(normalcount),normalcount)
    names(normalcount)[1] <- "geneID"
    return(normalcount)
  }
####RPKM的计算结果展示----
  output$RPKMtable <- renderTable({
    return(head(RPKMResultTable(),n=30))
  },striped=TRUE,bordered = TRUE,width = "auto")
####RPKM结果文件的下载----
  output$downRPKMsult <- downloadHandler(
    filename = "RPKM.csv",
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(RPKMResultTable(), file, row.names = FALSE)
    }
  )
####Riborex包的差异分析----
  # output$diffTable <- renderTable({
  #   req(input$file3)
  #   req(input$file4)
  #   req(input$file5)
  #   req(input$file6)
  #   geneMatrixRNA <- read.csv(input$file3$datapath,header = TRUE,row.names=1)
  #   geneMatrixRibo <- read.csv(input$file4$datapath,header = TRUE,row.names=1)
  #   rnaCond <- read.csv(input$file5$datapath,header=TRUE)
  #   riboCond <- read.csv(input$file6$datapath,header =TRUE)
  #   geneMatrixRNA <- as.data.frame(geneMatrixRNA)
  #   geneMatrixRibo <- as.data.frame(geneMatrixRibo)
  #   rnaCond <- as.data.frame(rnaCond)
  #   riboCond <- as.data.frame(riboCond)
  #   #对上传文件进行必要判断
  #   if (!identical(rownames(geneMatrixRNA), rownames(geneMatrixRibo)))
  #     stop ("RNA- and Ribo-seq data must have the same set of genes")
  #   if (!identical(colnames(rnaCond), colnames(riboCond)))
  #     stop("RNA- and Ribo-seq data must have the same set of conditions")
  #   minMeanCount <- 1
  #   if (ncol(geneMatrixRNA) != nrow(rnaCond))
  #     stop(paste("RNA-seq count table must have the",
  #                "same number of samples as in rnaCond"))
  #   if (ncol(geneMatrixRibo) != nrow(riboCond))
  #     stop(paste("Ribo-seq count table must have the",
  #                "same number of samples as in riboCond"))
  #   #数据清洗
  #   keep.rna <- rownames(geneMatrixRNA)[rowMeans(geneMatrixRNA) >= minMeanCount]
  #   keep.ribo <- rownames(geneMatrixRibo)[rowMeans(geneMatrixRibo) >= minMeanCount]
  #   keep <- intersect(keep.rna, keep.ribo)
  #   geneMatrixRNA <- geneMatrixRNA[keep,]
  #   geneMatrixRibo <- geneMatrixRibo[keep,]
  #   
  #   numCond <- nrow(rnaCond)
  #   TempCondition <-  c(rep("CONTROL", numCond/2), rep("TREATED", numCond/2))
  #   rnaCond <- cbind(rnaCond,TempCondition)
  #   riboCond <- cbind(riboCond,TempCondition)
  #   
  #   
  #   res <- riborex(geneMatrixRNA,geneMatrixRibo,rnaCond$TempCondition,riboCond$TempCondition)
  #   res <- as.data.frame(res)
  #   res[,c("baseMean","lfcSE","stat")] <- NULL
  #   res <- res%>%
  #     mutate(padj = ifelse(is.na(padj), 1, padj))
  #   diffGeneId <- rownames(res)
  #   diffGeneId <- as.data.frame(diffGeneId)
  #   res <- cbind(diffGeneId,res)
  #   names(res)[1] <- "GeneID" 
  #   return(head(res,n=14))
  #   
  # })
####PCA绘图----
  PCAplot <- function(){
    req(input$geneExpressDataFile)
    geneMatrix_3 <- read.csv(input$geneExpressDataFile$datapath,row.names = 1,header = T)
    group <- as.data.frame(setUpGroup(geneMatrix_3))
    names(group) <- "sample"
    group <- cbind(colnames(geneMatrix_3),group)
    geneMatrix_3 <- dataPreprocessing(geneMatrix_3)
    tempValue <- length(unique(setUpGroup(geneMatrix_3)))
    pca.res <- prcomp(t(geneMatrix_3))
    pca.res <- fviz_pca_ind(pca.res,label="none",
                            title="Principal component analysis(PCA)",
                            habillage = group$sample,
                            addEllipses = TRUE,
                            ellipse.level=0.95,
                            palette = PCAcolorBank[1:tempValue])
    return(pca.res)
  }
####PCA绘图展示----
  output$PCAplot <- renderPlot({
    PCAplot()
  },res = 120)
####PCA绘图文件下载----
  output$downPCAplot <- downloadHandler(
    filename = "PCA.pdf",
    content = function(file){
      pdf(file)
      print(PCAplot())
      dev.off()
    }
  )
})
```

Reload." factoextra is loaded in the server, so I commented it, the server will not be disconnected, but I need to use this package, how should I solve it。

Comment: Find the server/app logs. Getting a disconnect message is usually (not always) indicative of code failure; this may be because an underlying os library cannot be found, breaking a package that otherwise works on your local machine. (Another reason for the "disconnect" can be timeout or other server things.)